# data sent and received through tcp socket not the same

Tags: python, c++, sockets, tcp

## My data sent and received through a tcp connection doesn't match up.

I have a raspberry hosting a tcp server written in c++. This is used only by my python module using python's `socket` module. I send a string to which the server responds with with an unsigned short integer. What I send and receive seem to be completely different. Some examples:

```
| sent in hex | received as string |
| ----------- | ------------------ |
| 0xb6fc      |  b'\x0b\xaa'       | 
| 0x80f5      |  b'\xb6h'          |
| 0xf93b      |  b'X\xec           |
| 0x3167      |  b'\x95\x1b'       |
```

The only consistent factor is the size. There are always 2 bytes send and 2 bytes received. I tried using `struct.unpack` on the received data and got a completely different value.

## source code

this is running on the server

```cpp
unsigned short value = 0;

std::thread count_thr(counter, &toggle, &value);

while (1){
            memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
            received = recv(new_fd, &buf, sizeof buf, 0);
            printf("received string: %s\n", buf);

            if (strcmp(buf, "exit") == 0){
                    printf("closing server...\n");
                    close(new_fd);
                    exit(0);
            }
            else if (strcmp(buf, "get") == 0){
                    int bytes_sent = send(new_fd, &value, sizeof value, 0);
                    printf("sending value: %x\nbytes sent: %i\n", value, bytes_sent);
            }
    }
```

and this on the client

```py
try:
sock.sendall('get'.encode())
    data = sock.recv(32)
    length = len(data)
    print('data received: %s\nlength: %i' % (data, len(data)))
except OSError as error:
    msg = str(error)
```

Comment: What does `count_thr` do?

Comment: it starts a separate thread, which constantly changes `value`. It could actually be that, since it might change `value` while `send` is trying to send it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you just discovered, this is a self-inflicted race condition.
The fix is easy: just take a local copy of `value` that will not be changed by the external thread before sending:

```
unsigned short copy = value;
int bytes_sent = send(new_fd, &copy, sizeof copy, 0);
printf("sending value: %x\nbytes sent: %i\n", copy, bytes_sent);
```

Comment: I just tested this, and it didn't solve the problem. The received and send values still don't match

Comment: Can you change the type of `value` to `std::atomic_ushort`? That can force the compiler to actually do the read once and store the result into `copy`.

Comment: i've removed the whole thread call, and just stored a simple ushort in `value`, this seems to have some effects. first when I changed `value` to always be 6969, I received `b'9\x1b'`. and when I set `value` to `0xabcd` I received `b'\xcd\xab`. The bytes seem to be in the incorrect order, but that's not a problem. I don't understand what happens when the string doesn't have 2 `\x` in it though.

Comment: 6969 = 0x1b39. ASCII `9` = 0x39. Check for yourself with `struct.pack("<H", 6969)` in Python. Then pass that value to `bytes.hex` to get `391b`

Comment: alright, that would mean the data I get might be correct, just the decoding that's wrong

Answer (score 1):

as Botje said, I had a race condition since the data of `value` was constantly being changed while sending it. Another problem was the unclear data I received, but it turns out it were ASCII characters instead of the hexadecimal representation of the byte.

with that sorted out,

```py
decoded_val = struct.unpack('<H', data)[0]
```

this line solved my problem. I added the `[0]` since unpack returned a tuple, and the first item contained the correct value.